# Преобразование типов для отрицательной строки

Tags: javascript

Добрый день, подскажите, почему в Javascript минус перед "строкой" превращает ее в число?

Например:

```
typeof (-"30"); // number;
typeof ("30"); // string;
```

Спасибо!!

Comment: мб потому что минус это унарный оператор работающий с числами, что неявно приводит строку к числу?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Согласно спецификации](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-unary-minus-operator)

> The unary - operator converts its operand to Number type and then negates it. Negating +0 produces −0, and negating −0 produces +0.

> Оператор "Унарный **–**" преобразует свой операнд к типу Number и затем инвертирует знак. Инвертирование для `+0` даст `−0`, и для `−0` - `+0`.

Далее следует [алгоритм работы данного оператора](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-unary-minus-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation):

1. Вычислить выражение
2. Вызвать `ToNumber`
3. Если результат `NaN` вернуть `NaN`
4. Вернуть результат полученный на втором шаге с инвертированным знаком.